# Как передать данные из контроллера в частичное представление ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, razor, asp-net-core-mvc

Есть метод контроллера:

```
public ActionResult AdminPanelWidget()
{
     Statistic model = new Statistic
     {
         AllUsersCount = _context.Users.Count(),
         Admins = 0,
         Buyers = 0,
         Sellers = 0,
         Notices = 0
     };
     return PartialView("AdminPanelWidget", model);
        }
```

Есть частичное представление:

```
@model StreletzNoticeBoard.Areas.Admin.Models.Statistic
    <div>
        <h4>Сведения</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Admins)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Admins)
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sellers)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Sellers)
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Buyers)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Buyers)
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AllUsersCount)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AllUsersCount)
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notices)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Notices)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

На странице Index вывожу частичное представление так:

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Статистика</h2>
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("AdminPanelWidget");}
    </div>
```

Выводятся только названия позиций статистики без данных. Вызов метода контроллера не происходит

Как сделать чтобы метод контроллера вызывался и в частичное представление поступали данные?

Comment: при рендеринге передать модель в `RenderPartialAsync`, либо через AJAX получать `PartialView` и добавлять в DOM через JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче, всё-таки разобрался сам.

Дело в том, что в ASP.NET Core MVC, в отличие от классического ASP.NET MVC, отсутствуют дочерние действия, которые были в классическом ASP.NET MVC. Поэтому приведённый в вопросе приём в  ASP.NET Core MVC никак не прокатит.

Вместо контроллеров для этих целей в ASP.NET Core MVC необходимо использовать ViewComponents. Статья в документации Microsoft с подробной инструкцией: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.0.